How to properly highlight TypeScript compiler error messages with pygments
For example, the following code leads to a compilation error:
const a: number = '';

Error message is:
a.ts:1:7 - error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

1 const a: number = '';
        ~


Found 1 error in a.ts:1

What is the proper way to highlight this error message with Pygments? (e.g., is there a specific lexer?)

There's a list of supported languages: https://pygments.org/languages/. TypeScript errors doesn't appear to be one.
